# permission denied while building hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, ssh

I would like to build a hadoop cluster with one master machine and 3 slave machines. I can ssh to any slave machine by code like `ssh slave1`, but I got error while building cluster, and it kept asking me for the password. I have input the correct ones, but the program still failed.

```
hadoop@master:~$ start-dfs.sh
17/10/24 13:46:15 WARN hdfs.DFSUtilClient: Namenode for null remains unresolved for ID null. Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: ssh: Could not resolve hostname master: Temporary failure in name resolution
hadoop@slave1's password: hadoop@slave3's password: hadoop@slave2's password: 
hadoop@slave3's password: slave3: Permission denied, please try again.

hadoop@slave3's password: slave3: Permission denied, please try again.

hadoop@slave1's password: slave1: Permission denied, please try again.

hadoop@slave2's password: slave2: Permission denied, please try again.

slave1: Permission denied, please try again.
hadoop@slave1's password: 
hadoop@slave2's password: slave2: Permission denied, please try again.

slave1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
23571113

slave3: Permission denied (publickey,password).
23571113

slave2: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamemaster.out
```

Comment: Well, you need to setup the `authorized_keys` file to have a shared **password-less** key. It sounds like you have given a password when you created the key

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for reply. I have already setup it, and put three slaves' and a master's key (ssh-rsa ....) into it

Comment: Yes, but it looks like that key requires a password

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you use `ssh-copy-id` rather than just create that file and add a line